# ControlsFX font Awesome don't show icons

Tags: javafx-8, font-awesome, fxml, controlsfx

To iconify my application i decided to use ControlFX's Font awesome support.

I tried to use it in both Code and FXML, and the result only to "GEAR" icon that works.

So, what makes other icon not showing up ?

her is the code for FXML file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>


<?import org.controlsfx.glyphfont.Glyph?>
<fx:root maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="400.0" prefWidth="600.0" type="AnchorPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" fx:controller="testController">
   <children>
      <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" >
          <graphic>
            // The Gear icon works perfectly 
            <Glyph fontFamily="FontAwesome" icon="GEAR"/>  
            <Glyph fontFamily="FontAwesome" icon="SEARCH"/>
          </graphic>
      </Button>
   </children>
</fx:root>
```

I want also to change the color of the icon after getting it work.

Answer (score 5):

It seems you want two graphics in one JavaFX Button element. According to the [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/Button.html), this is not possible.

> The button control can contain text and/or a graphic.

The Button class' methods also indicate that at most, only one graphic can be set to a button.

Given the inherent, semantic difference between 'GEAR' and 'SEARCH', I believe you may want two buttons. Try:

```
...
<children>
    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Button" >
        <graphic>
            // the gear graphic
            <Glyph fontFamily="FontAwesome" icon="GEAR"/>  
        </graphic>
    </Button>
    <Button mnemonicParsing="false" text="Search" >
        <graphic>
            // the search graphic
            <Glyph fontFamily="FontAwesome" icon="SEARCH"/>
        </graphic>
    </Button>
</children>
...
```